# Can't use 'force user = root' and 'follow symlinks = no' at the same time

Tags: samba

I'm configuring a read-only "backup" samba share for a third party backup solution on Windows to backup '/' on one server.  The server is running RHEL 6 and samba 3.6.9 (default from package management).

The issue is that when both 'force user = root' and 'follow symlinks = no' are enabled I receive a permission denied error trying to list any directory under '/' regardless of permissions (listing the root tree is curiously fine...).  If I disable either option on the share I am able to browse just fine (however without setting the user to root large parts of the tree are unavailable to the backup software).  Without the ability to disable symlinks the backup software falls into an infinite loop.

Here are the relevant parts of my smb.conf file (global and the share itself):

```
[global]
    workgroup = CORP
    realm = CORP.LOCAL
    server string = Samba Server Version %v
    interfaces = lo, xxx.xxx.xxx.59/24
    security = ADS
    password server = theman.corp.local helmet.corp.local
    map untrusted to domain = Yes
    log level = 3
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 50
    time server = Yes
    unix extensions = No
    cups options = raw
    veto oplock files = /*.tif/*.pcl/*pclimg*/*tifimg*/*.mp3/*swpcl*/*splimg*/
    wide links = Yes
    idmap uid = 10000-20000
    idmap gid = 10000-20000
...
[backup]
    comment = Backup
    path = /
    force user = root
    force group = root
    browseable = Yes
    valid users = backup
    read only = Yes
    #follow symlinks = No
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

(Note: Assume we can't ditch the backup software.  I have my own rsync scripts to back up and restore the server, but we're exploring other options for central management of backups).